# WifiNetworkSpecifier - auto connect when single network available

Tags: android

I'm establishing a connection to a specified network by ssid/pass using WifiNetworkSpecifier. Below is my code:

```
                            specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                                    .setSsid(this.ssid)
                                    .setWpa2Passphrase(this.pass)
                                    .build();
                            NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_TRUSTED)
                                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
                                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)
                                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_VPN)
                                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_FOREGROUND)
                                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_CONGESTED)
                                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_SUSPENDED)
                                    .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_ROAMING)
                                    .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                                    .build();
                            cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            callback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onUnavailable() {
                                   [....]
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                                    [....]
                                }
                            };
                            cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, callback, TIMEOUT);
```

And here is my question. **Can I auto connect to the only network available?** The behaviour now  is like this : a popup displayed with the only network available and I have to tap connect. I see it as an useless step for my app. 
Mention: It is an internal app and I always have to be connected on my local wifi.

Thank you!